# Keystore Not Found for Signing Config 'release'

Tags: flutter, dart, build, apk, keystore

I'm having a problem while running this command on Flutter: `flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64` which I need to run in order to execute `flutter build apk`.

build.gradle

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

key.properties

```
storePassword=XXXX
keyPassword=XXXX
keyAlias=key
storeFile="C:/Users/User/Key/key.jks"
```

Error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file 'D:\Projects\Flutter\iusefully\android\app\"C:\Users\User\Key\key.jks"' not found for signing config 'release'.
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I finally found the answer,
my problem was in the `key.properties` file.
The problem occurred because I used `storeFile="LOC"`
The declartion of this variable for the path of the `.jks` should NOT be in `" "`
quotation.

WRONG:
`storeFile="C:/Users/User/Key/key.jks"`

RIGHT: `storeFile=C:/Users/User/Key/key.jks`

In addition, I added the `key.jks` file to the `/app` folder.

Answer (score 9):

this solution work for me...
follow this instruction

https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#create-a-keystore

and in key.properties don't put values inside `""`
ex:

```
storePassword=454545
keyPassword=456565
keyAlias=upload
storeFile= C:/Users/{profile}/upload-keystore.jks
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your key location c to d drive...
Same time permission issue occurred with c drive

Answer (score 2):

You need to copy all paths, see the below image:

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Answer (score 1):

For my case , changing

```
password = myapp@123
keyAlais = myapp
jksFileName = myapp_keystore
```

into

```
password = myapp@123
keyAlais = myapp
jksFileName = myapp_keystore.jks
```

resolved the issue. Just add `.jks` extension in the keystore file name in `key.properties`

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to rename file
`{home}\.android\debug.keystore` to `{home}\.android\debug.keystore.jks`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to t0m3r's answer, when running the command below on windows: change `USER_NAME` to your user name

```
 keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\USER_NAME\upload-keystore.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store your `key.jks` near with `key.properties` then set path:

```
storeFile=../key.jks
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I was misplacing the `upload-keystore.jks`.
if you want to put the `upload-keystore.jks` inside the project then it should be at:`project->android->app`
and In your `key.properties` put `storeFile=upload-keystore.jks`:

```
storePassword=YOU_STORE_PASSWORD
keyPassword=YOUR_KEYPASSWORD
keyAlias=upload
storeFile=upload-keystore.jks
```

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin/Java user to set keystore path.
build.gradle (Module:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}
def keyProperties = new  Properties()
def path = rootProject.file("gradle.properties")
if (path.exists()) {
    keyProperties.load( new FileInputStream(path))
}
android {
    namespace 'phone.clone.mypractice'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "phone.clone.mypractice"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        create("release") {
            storeFile = file(keyProperties["storeFile"] as String)
            keyPassword = keyProperties["keyPassword"] as String
            storePassword = keyProperties["storePassword"] as String
            keyAlias = keyProperties["keyAlias"] as String
        }
        create("Testing") {
            storeFile = file(keyProperties["storeFile"] as String)
            keyPassword = keyProperties["keyPassword"] as String
            storePassword = keyProperties["storePassword"] as String
            keyAlias = keyProperties["keyAlias"] as String
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField("String", "Base_Url", "\"https://www.google.com\"")
            signingConfig = signingConfigs["release"]
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            versionNameSuffix "-debug"
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField("String", "Base_Url", "\"https://www.google.com\"")
        }
        create("Testing") {
            initWith(getByName("debug"))// it takes all the properties of debug varaint.
            buildConfigField("String", "Base_Url", "\"https://www.google.com\"")
            signingConfig signingConfigs["Testing"]
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        buildConfig true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

gradle.properties (Project Properties)

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
# AndroidX package structure to make it clearer which packages are bundled with the
# Android operating system, and which are packaged with your app's APK
# https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=true
# Kotlin code style for this project: "official" or "obsolete":
kotlin.code.style=official
# Enables namespacing of each library's R class so that its R class includes only the
# resources declared in the library itself and none from the library's dependencies,
# thereby reducing the size of the R class for that library
android.nonTransitiveRClass=true

storeFile= D:/practice/MyApplication/keystore/practice.jks
storePassword = practice
keyPassword = practice
keyAlias = key0
```