# how to change the path of keystore to build release mode in Flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, android-keystore, flutter-android

I try to install android app on my real device using release mode using

```
flutter run --release
```

or build an APK using

```
flutter build apk
```

but I have this error in my Flutter app

> Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file '/Users/myName/Documents/thisIsTheOldPath/my_keystore' not found for signing config 'release'.

I am using Mac. previously I change the location of my keystore, but when I run the app, the system still pointing to the old path. how to change the path of my keystore? so I can run my app in release mode using the latest keystore path

I have tried to search on Stackoverflow, from this thread [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62173655/keystore-not-found-for-signing-config-release) . it seems the path is in in `key.properties` file, but I can't find `key.properties` file in my Android directory like so:

[image]

Comment: Can you share your `android/app/build.gradle`?

Comment: @Stijn2210 you are right, I can find it on  android --> signingConfigs --> release